# Как отследить в puppeteer добавление нового блока на страницу?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

На страницу каждые несколько секунд добавляется новый блок `div[data-role="recent-number"]`

При этом кол-во блоков не изменяется, так как удаляется последний.

Мне нужно словить событие когда добавился новый элемент с `div[data-role="recent-number"]`

Как можно это сделать?

Comment: mutationObserver - вроде бы

Answer (score 1):

```js
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
      console.log('>> "' + mutation.addedNodes[i].textContent + '" added');
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < mutation.removedNodes.length; i++) {
      console.log('>> "' + mutation.removedNodes[i].textContent + '" removed');
    }
  });
});
observer.observe(foo, {
  childList: true
});

// проверки
var bar = document.createElement('div');
bar.textContent = 'bar';
console.log('before append [synchronous]');
foo.appendChild(bar);
console.log('after append [synchronous]');
console.log('before remove [synchronous]');
foo.removeChild(bar);
console.log('after remove [synchronous]');

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('before append [asynchronous]');
  foo.appendChild(bar);
  console.log('after append [asynchronous]');
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('before remove [asynchronous]');
    foo.removeChild(bar);
    console.log('after remove [asynchronous]');
  });
});
```

```html
<div id='foo'></div>
```

Comment: видели в вопросе метку [tag:puppeteer]?

Comment: @nörbörnën, в чем суть вашего комментария?

Comment: ну как бы вот суть: "как ваш ответ применить, если страница загружена в puppeteer?"

Comment: page.evaluate для запуска кода и page.exposeFunction для "обратной связи". Люди которые работают с puppeteer прекрасно знают эти методы. Смысл это расписывать? Да и life example с ними не будет работать у нас на SO

Comment: "Люди которые работают с puppeteer прекрасно знают" вряд ли, iKey в их числе